# Resolving relative paths with wildcards in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wildcard, relative-path, path-combine

In C#, if I have a directory path and a relative file path with wildcard, e.g.

`"c:\foo\bar"` and `"..\blah\*.cpp"`

Is there a simple way to get the list of absolute file paths? e.g.

`{ "c:\foo\blah\a.cpp", "c:\foo\blah\b.cpp" }`

**Background**

There is a source code tree, where any directory can contain a build definition file. This file uses relative paths with wildcards to specify a list of source files. The task is to generate a list of absolute paths of all source files for each one of these build definition files.

Comment: System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles allows you to specify wildcards in the searchpattern param, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233.aspx and will return absolute paths

Comment: @Polity, System.ArgumentException: Search pattern cannot contain ".." to move up directories

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the absolute path first and then enumerate the files inside the directory matching the wildcard:

```
// input
string rootDir = @"c:\foo\bar"; 
string originalPattern = @"..\blah\*.cpp";

// Get directory and file parts of complete relative pattern
string pattern = Path.GetFileName (originalPattern); 
string relDir = originalPattern.Substring ( 0, originalPattern.Length - pattern.Length );
// Get absolute path (root+relative)
string absPath = Path.GetFullPath ( Path.Combine ( rootDir ,relDir ) );

// Search files mathing the pattern
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles ( absPath, pattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly );
```

Comment: Path.GetFullPath() throws ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path, if the path contains any wildcard.

Comment: You're right, I updated my code so that the relative search pattern is first divided into directory- and file-information and afterwards the absolute path is determined

Comment: It works! Even better, rather than
`string relDir = originalPattern.Substring ( 0, originalPattern.Length - pattern.Length );`
We can use 
`string relDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(originalPattern);`

Comment: This works well, but only when no wildcards are used in the directory names of the relative path, like in the specific example provided by the question.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple.

```
using System.IO;
      .
      .
      .
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```